# Declare multiple variables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am new to SQL and trying to determine how to set a variable to either *A* or *B*.
Here is the statement:

```
DECLARE @Planner AS VARCHAR(50) = '2566927' OR @Planner = '12201704'
```

And the error I am receiving:

> The following errors occurred during execution of the SQL query:
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OR'.

Here is a more complete sample:

```
DECLARE
@Planner AS VARCHAR(50) = '2566927'

--Temp Table for Final
CREATE TABLE #PP1(
  Part_Key varChar(50)
  ,Part_No varChar(50)
  ,Part_Name varChar(50)
  ,CurInv DECIMAL(10,2)
  ,MinInv DECIMAL(10,2)
  ,Past_Due DECIMAL(10,2)
  ,Week2 DECIMAL(10,2)
  ,Week4 DECIMAL(10,2)
  ,Week8 DECIMAL(10,2)
  ,Week12 DECIMAL(10,2)
  ,Plus12 DECIMAL(10,2)
  ,Dep26w DECIMAL(10,1)
  ,Stock DECIMAL(10,1)
  ,StockPur DECIMAL (10,1)
  )

--Temp Table to Limit Parts
CREATE TABLE #MRP_Parts(
  MRP_PK varChar(50)
  ,MRP_PN varChar(50)
  ,MRP_PNAME varChar(50)
  )

--Insert into Temp Part Table
INSERT #MRP_Parts

SELECT

PP.Part_Key
,PP.Part_No
,PP.Name

FROM Part_v_Part AS PP
WHERE (PP.Planner = @Planner OR @Planner = '')

--BEGIN Temp Table for Inventory
CREATE TABLE #CurrInv(
  CI_Part_Key varChar(50)
  ,CI_Part_No varChar(50)
  ,CI_Qty DECIMAL(10,1)
  ,CI_Min DECIMAL(10,2)
  )

INSERT #CurrInv

SELECT

PP.PArt_Key
,PP.Part_No
,ISNULL(PC1.Quantity,0)
,PP.Minimum_Inventory_Quantity

FROM Part_v_Part AS PP
OUTER APPLY
(
  SELECT
    SUM(PC.Quantity) AS Quantity
  FROM Part_v_Container as PC
  WHERE PP.part_Key=PC.part_Key
    AND (PC.Container_Status = 'OK' 
      OR PC.Container_Status = 'Receiving'
      OR PC.Container_Status = 'Testing Hold')
    AND PC.Active = '1'
    AND (PP.Planner = @Planner OR @Planner = '')
) AS PC1
```

What I would like is for the @Planner to be either A or B

Comment: you cannot do this.  please ask your question a different way

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: You cannot set a variable to "either A or B": it must have *one* value. Please edit explaining what you want to do

Comment: A variable holds a value. One value. What are you trying to do?

Comment: you need some specific condition to set either or value for variable.

Comment: Here is more of the statement...I suppose I could create a second variable?

Comment: @user9324484 A **second** variable ***must have*** a _different_ name.

Comment: @user9324484 Make up your mind.  Why would a variable have 2 values??  How would you know which value to assign???  It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @JNevill Was support dropped for table variables?

Comment: @HABO hardy har har. You could also stick a comma delimited list in a varchar variable and store as many values as you like... Or you could write the two values down on a post it note and stick it on your monitor.

Answer (score 21):

A second variable must have a different name. E.g.

```
DECLARE  @Planner1 VARCHAR(50) = '2566927',
         @Planner2 varchar(10) = '12201704',
         @OtherVar int = 42
```

And separate each variable declaration with a comma `,`

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that, but you can declare a variable as a table and put multiple values into the table

```
DECLARE @Planner AS TABLE (P VARCHAR(50))
INSERT @Planner SELECT '2566927' 
INSERT @Planner SELECT '12201704'
```

And then you can use the table variable in a `where in` type clause

```
SELECT
    PP.Part_Key
    ,PP.Part_No
    ,PP.Name
FROM Part_v_Part AS PP
WHERE PP.Planner IN (SELECT P FROM @Planner)
```